# Alternating rails image_uploader.rb generated <div class="one/other"> in app's .erb view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an image uploader that adds sample cover pictures to a containing row `<div class=”row”>`.  The images render in their own  tags with class=”rotation” like `<div class=”rotation”>`.  I need to also alternate that class between `“rotation”` and `“rotation-alt”` in order to apply alternating rotations with CSS.  How can I alternate which tag is rendered with each upload in a rails .erb view?

The .erb currently looks like this:

```
  <%= link_to "Upload New Photo", new_cover_path, class: "btn" %>

  <div class="row">
    <% @covers.each do |cover| %>

    <div class="rotation">
        <%= link_to image_tag(cover.photo.url(:thumb), :class => 'img-responsive'), image_path(cover.photo.url), :class => 'thumbnail' if cover.photo? %>
    </div>

    <% end %>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cycle` method

Eg:

```
class="<%= cycle("rotation", "rotation_alt", name: "row_class") -%>"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works beautifully!  I was about to try using CSS3 nth-child pseudo selectors, but your way is much nicer. :)